# Collections Sorting in Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

Whats wrong with this sort? It doesn't work properly.

```
 public List<LibRegistration> getLibraryRegistrationsSortedByTypeAndName()
    {
        List<LibRegistration> l = getLibRegs();
        Collections.sort(l, new Comparator<LibRegistration>() {
            public int compare(LibRegistration o1, LibRegistration o2) {
               return o1.getLibraryType().compareTo(o2.getLibraryType()) != 0?o1.getLibraryType().compareTo(o2.getLibraryType()):o1.getLibraryName().compareTo(o2.getLibraryName());
            }
        });
        return l;
    }
```

Comment: In what way does it not work correctly?

Comment: What behaviour were you expecting that you did not see?  What output does it produce?

Comment: It looks fine to me. getLibraryType, getLibraryName or your compareTo usage may be faulty - or not what you expected.

Comment: what error/warning are u getting ? is it compile time or run-time? Can you paste here the code for LibRegistration ?

Comment: Make your Comparator a "normal" public class in a separate file and write unit tests for it. Your one liner in the anonymous class is hardly readable, maybe you should use a few more lines.

Comment: You have to make sure that LibraryType (what getLibraryType returns) implements the interface Comparable.

Answer (score 4):

Nothing wrong, more clear:

```
        public int compare(LibRegistration o1, LibRegistration o2) {
            int cmp = o1.getLibraryType().compareTo(o2.getLibraryType());
            if (cmp == 0)
                cmp = o1.getLibraryName().compareTo(o2.getLibraryName());
            return cmp;
        }
```

Though nulls not allowed and compareTo well defined.

Comment: It's strange. I expected it to work in the fashion of a SQL query **order by** clause but it gives unexpected ordering. So I just concatenated the two strings(type and name)  and did a compareTo once on the concatenated String. I suppose it's faster performance wise too. But Is till want to know if my logic is flawed in getting it to behave as a SQL ORDER BY. Any advice or explanations?

Comment: It's strange. I expected it to work in the fashion of a SQL query **order by** clause but it gives unexpected ordering. So I just concatenated the two strings(type and name)  and did a compareTo once on the concatenated String. I suppose it's faster performance wise too. But Is till want to know if my logic is flawed in getting it to behave as a SQL ORDER BY. Any advice or explanations?

@NPE

Comment: SQL ORDER BY involves **case sensitivity** and **language locale** too. You can do similar in Java too. If you work with MySQL, you have a candidate with its own often misused locales.